# Formatting C/C++ code with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, c

I've been using Visual Studio 2022 for the last few months, and I want to have my C and C++ code formatted with the following style:

```
if (someCondition) {

    // Do something

} else if (someOtherCodition) {

   // Do something else

} else {

   // Otherwise

}
```

However, after entering the code with the above format, the IDE displays the code with the following format on reload:

```
if (someCondition) {

    // Do something

}
else if (someOtherCodition) {

   // Do something else

}
else {

   // Otherwise

}
```

which looks very untidy. How do I configure the IDE to keep the format that I enter? This is not really a programming question, but would appreciate some guidance. There must be an option that can be changed, but I can't find it.

Comment: I would use clang format and then you can customize the formatting to your hearts content

Answer (score 3):

Reset/uncheck the option "Place 'else' on new line".

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, it works, and saved me some time! There are some other options which I may want to change.